# System.Web load exception in class library when using adapters

Tags: c#, system.web

I am trying to migrate some old API to .net 6. I am using for that new [System.Web adapters](https://github.com/dotnet/systemweb-adapters).
Just to verify when I use `HttpContext.Current` in .net 6 API project everything is fine.

Problem is that one of the older class library projects is using `HttpContext`.Current and referencing System.Web. I removed System.Web reference, added reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters`. I cleaned project, deleted `bin/obj` folders. But when I debug, it is still always trying to load `System.Web` library instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters`. Even Visual studio when I navigate to HttpContext implementation inside older class library project points me to System.Web. Target framework of class lib is net472.

Any suggestions what else can be done?

Comment: `System.Web` is old in .NET Framework too. The adapters are there only to help with the initial migration. What does that library do and why does it need a singleton HttpContext? There's no such thing since ASP.NET Web API - that's before even ASP.NET Core 1.0. If the library has a valid reason to use HttpContext you should pass it as a parameter

Comment: As for your specific error, the only way that library would try to load System.Web.dll would be to have a direct or indirect reference to it. What does your `csproj` look like? Does it reference old libraries that in turn reference System.Web? Or use NuGet packages that require System.Web ?

Comment: I double checked my references and i removed system.web from every projects. So i digged more and actually the library Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters is referencing System.Web itself if you include it in old.net framework. So now i either have to solve Typeload exception which i will probably wont since it will be loaded by net 6 api, or i should multitarget the old one class lib.

Comment: `if you include it in old.net framework` but you aren't doing that, you're including it in .NET Core. There shouldn't be a problem. Besides, I already explained that your code would fail even in ASP.NET Web API 4.7.2.

Comment: Besides, the adapters are nothing more than a quick&dirty fix. Again, Web API. And testing - using HttpContext.Current made unit testing of WebForms/MVC apps a very big pain which is why people tried to avoid it even before 2012. You're trying to use a 20-year old namespace that was deprecated 10 years ago in a modern runtime. The adapters can help you get your code working in one way or another until you migrate it to the current API